# How to remove closed app’s entry from windows alt-tab menu?

Tags: windows, windows-11, alt-tab

When I close some specific apps, they still exist in the windows alt-tab menu ? Happens with specific apps only (here `shapez` game). App is closed, there is no instance running in the task manager but it shows in the windows alt tab menu.

How do I remove this?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: I believe there's something wrong with your explorer. Did you try to restart it?

Comment: Restarting PC does fix the issue but I was looking for commands/steps that reset it or something like that.

Comment: I meant restarting the explorer, not the entire PC :-)

Comment: If it shows in the alt tab menu, then a process exists. Try to switch to it.

Comment: @Dominique Thank You. It worked.